# Connect two devices in LAN with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I am an web programmer, but I have a hard problem (and my english is bad).
I have to send some data (a byte or two only) over LAN/Internet from one device (w/ browser) to another. The problem is that the 2nd device is passive and so it doesn't act like a computer, just accepts the signal. I have to make the script in HTML5/JS because PHP doesn't work.

Comment: browser can send data to a server, but can't communicate with another device. Other device would have to communicate with same server

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give you help when it's a bit unclear what you're attempting to accomplish. However I'm gonna assume you have internet access, and am thinking of using a browser.

If it's not important, for myself, and if I'm not too bothered; I would do something like this:
CLIENT: Has a script that posts information to PHP, that saves it either in a file or a database.
RECIEVING COMPUTER: Has a website open that checks wether or not any data has been saved, through the use of an javascript-interval or META-REFRESH.

If I am bothered however, I would probably use node.js to create what you're looking for:
http://nodejs.org/

Though hard to say without really knowing what you're after exactly...